# large datetime objects pandas causing out of memory

Tags: pandas, datetime, memory, time-series, vectorization

I have a big txt file (~300 mb) with values and shape like:

```
df= pd.read_csv('file.txt')
df.head()

   <Base> <DTYYYYMMDD>  <TIME>  <p1>    <p2>    <p3>    <p4>    <q>
36  x       20010102    235700  0.5622  0.5622  0.5622  0.5622  4
37  x       20010102    235800  0.5622  0.5622  0.5622  0.5622  4
38  x       20010102    235900  0.5622  0.5622  0.5622  0.5622  4
39  x       20010103    0       0.5618  0.5618  0.5618  0.5618  4
40  x       20010103    300     0.5622  0.5622  0.5622  0.5622  4
41  x       20010103    500     0.5622  0.5622  0.5622  0.5622  4

df.shape()

(5560000, 8)
```

I am trying to get just the value p4 and plot the number of occurences in each year among other things. For this I am trying to first convert DTYYYYMMDD and TIME fields to strings (they are read as integers from text file), then convert them to datetime as follows:

```
datestr = df['<DTYYYYMMDD>'].apply(lambda x: str(x))
timestr = df['<TIME>'].apply(lambda x: str(x))
zeros = timestr.apply(lambda x: '0' * (6- len(x)))
timestr = zeros + timestr
dtstr = datestr + timestr
p4_df = df['<p4>']
dt_datetime = pd.to_datetime(dtstr, format = '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
p4_df.index = dt_datetime
```

Now I am trying to just get the date part separately so I can groupby that and count the occurences. I need to keep the full datetime index also since i need that in other calculations.

```
p4_df['Date'] = dt_datetime.apply(lambda x: x.date())
to_plot = p4_df.groupby(['Date'])['<p4>'].count()
to_plot.plot()
```

I get a memory error on `dt_datetime.apply` line. I tried using the following instead but still for the error:

```
p4_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(datestr, format = '%Y%m%d')
```

Any suggestions to make the code more memory efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) for convert to strings and then add zeros by [`zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html):

```
dtstr = df['<DTYYYYMMDD>'].astype(str) + df['<TIME>'].astype(str).str.zfill(6)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(dtstr, format = '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
print (df)
                    <Base>  <DTYYYYMMDD>  <TIME>    <p1>    <p2>    <p3>  \
2001-01-02 23:57:00      x      20010102  235700  0.5622  0.5622  0.5622   
2001-01-02 23:58:00      x      20010102  235800  0.5622  0.5622  0.5622   
2001-01-02 23:59:00      x      20010102  235900  0.5622  0.5622  0.5622   
2001-01-03 00:00:00      x      20010103       0  0.5618  0.5618  0.5618   
2001-01-03 00:03:00      x      20010103     300  0.5622  0.5622  0.5622   
2001-01-03 00:05:00      x      20010103     500  0.5622  0.5622  0.5622   

                       <p4>  <q>  
2001-01-02 23:57:00  0.5622    4  
2001-01-02 23:58:00  0.5622    4  
2001-01-02 23:59:00  0.5622    4  
2001-01-03 00:00:00  0.5618    4  
2001-01-03 00:03:00  0.5622    4  
2001-01-03 00:05:00  0.5622    4
```

Another better performance get if use [`DatetimeIndex.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.floor.html) for `dates`:

```
#if dont need omit NaNs use size instaed count
to_plot = df.groupby(df.index.floor('D'))['<p4>'].count()
to_plot.plot()
```

Or use [`date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.date.html):

```
to_plot = df.groupby(df.index.date)['<p4>'].count()
to_plot.plot()
```

---

Another idea is use only `<DTYYYYMMDD>`, then convert to `string` is not necessary:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['<DTYYYYMMDD>'], format = '%Y%m%d')
print (df)
             <Base>  <DTYYYYMMDD>  <TIME>    <p1>    <p2>    <p3>    <p4>  <q>
<DTYYYYMMDD>                                                                  
2001-01-02        x      20010102  235700  0.5622  0.5622  0.5622  0.5622    4
2001-01-02        x      20010102  235800  0.5622  0.5622  0.5622  0.5622    4
2001-01-02        x      20010102  235900  0.5622  0.5622  0.5622  0.5622    4
2001-01-03        x      20010103       0  0.5618  0.5618  0.5618  0.5618    4
2001-01-03        x      20010103     300  0.5622  0.5622  0.5622  0.5622    4
2001-01-03        x      20010103     500  0.5622  0.5622  0.5622  0.5622    4

to_plot = df.groupby(level=0)['<p4>'].count()
print (to_plot)
<DTYYYYMMDD>
2001-01-02    3
2001-01-03    3
Name: <p4>, dtype: int64
```

EDIT1: Better performance should be first aggregate by strings and then convert to datetime smaller aggregated output:

```
to_plot = df.groupby('<DTYYYYMMDD>')['<p4>'].count()
to_plot.index = pd.to_datetime(to_plot.index, format = '%Y%m%d')
print (to_plot)
<DTYYYYMMDD>
2001-01-02    3
2001-01-03    3
Name: <p4>, dtype: int64
```

EDIT2:

If need use variables in another code:

```
datestr = df['<DTYYYYMMDD>'].astype(str)
timestr = df['<TIME>'].astype(str).str.zfill(6)

dtstr = datestr + timestr

p4_df = df['<p4>']
dt_datetime = pd.to_datetime(dtstr, format = '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
p4_df.index = dt_datetime

p4_df['Date'] = dt_datetime.date()
to_plot = p4_df.groupby(['Date'])['<p4>'].count()
to_plot.plot()
```

Answer (score 0):

Same happened with me, as groupby / where consumes too much memory and we get Out of Memory error. The trick is to do operation on date / month / year and not on complete date and operation would work like a charm.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df["<DTYYYYMMDD>"], format = '%Y%m%d') ## convert to datetime format
df['Year'] = df.Date.dt.year ## can use month / date 
to_plot = df.groupby('Year')['Year'].count()  
to_plot.plot()
```

> ### if you have year/month on different columns use

```
 df.groupby(['Year','Month']['Month'].count()
```

Doing operations by year / month / date are much faster. no need to convert to string!